# Cannot build the Alljoyn sdk over iOS,

Tags: ios, alljoyn

I download the alljoyn's core for iOS by git,but another base server can't build, and I discovered the office iOS document content has lot of abnormality, because I can't find the documents written in the library on my build core file, the documents has longTime no update? My download version is *16.04*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a documentation from git repo:

```
git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/extras/webdocs.git
cd webdocs
git checkout stage-16.10
```

pay attention to docs/develop/api-guide/core/objc.md